# Pandas - How to dynamically get min and max value of each session in the column

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

So I have a dataframe similar to this:

```
timestamp   |   name   
------------+------------
   1        |    a
   1        |    b
   2        |    c
   2        |    d
   2        |    e
   3        |    f
   4        |    g
```

Essentially I want to get **min and max value of each timestamp session**(defined by unique timestamp value, there are 4 sessions in this example), the expected result would something like this:

```
timestamp   |   name   | start  | end  
------------+----------+--------+------
   1        |    a     |   1    |  2
   1        |    b     |   1    |  2
   2        |    c     |   2    |  3
   2        |    d     |   2    |  3
   2        |    e     |   2    |  3
   3        |    f     |   3    |  4
   4        |    g     |   4    |  4
```

I am thinking index on timestamp column, then "move up" the index by 1, yet this approach didn't work on the forth bucket in the example above.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

try `numpy.clip()`, such as `df['end']=numpy.clip(df['timestamp']+1, 0, 4)`